# How to re-execute D3 animation on a button click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to be able to re-execute D3 animation by clicking on the button.

This is how I tried to to it, but it does not work:

**index.html**

Relevant lines of code:

```
<button class="button" onclick="reexecute()">Re-execute</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

This is the extract from JavaScript code (see `function reexecute() {..}`)

```
// Load the data.
d3.json("data.json", function(data1) {

  var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d[0]; });

  // Add a title.
  dot.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Add an overlay for the wt label.
  var box = label.node().getBBox();

  var overlay = svg1.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("x", box.x)
        .attr("y", box.y)
        .attr("width", box.width)
        .attr("height", box.height)
        .on("mouseover", enableInteraction);

  // Start a transition that interpolates the data based on wt.
  svg1.transition()
      .duration(20000)
      .ease("linear")
      .tween("wt", tweenwt)
      .each("end", enableInteraction);

  function reexecute() {
    svg1.transition()
          .duration(20000)
          .ease("linear")
          .tween("wt", tweenwt)
          .each("end", enableInteraction);
  }
//...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself as follows:

```
  d3.select('button').on('click',function(d,i){
    svg1.transition()
          .duration(20000)
          .ease("linear")
          .tween("wt", tweenwt)
          .each("end", enableInteraction);
  });
```